# Got error in C#.NET based voice recognition application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, speech-recognition

I've been trying to write this speech recognition app for a college project. I am learning C# on my self and I'm pretty new to it. I got this error when i tried to build the application, I got the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException   HResult=0x80070005
> Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
> (E_ACCESSDENIED))   Source=System.Speech   StackTrace:    at
> System.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.ISpRecognizer.GetFormat(SPSTREAMFORMATTYPE
> WaveFormatType, Guid& pFormatId, IntPtr& ppCoMemWFEX)    at
> System.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0()
> at
> System.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiProxy.PassThrough.Invoke(ObjectDelegate
> pfn)    at
> System.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.GetFormat(SPSTREAMFORMATTYPE
> WaveFormatType)    at
> System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.GetSapiAudioFormat()    at
> System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.UpdateAudioFormat(SpeechAudioFormatInfo
> audioFormat)    at
> System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
> at
> System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
> at RailVoice.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\Soorya S Rajan\source\repos\RailVoice\RailVoice\Form1.cs:line
> 35    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
> hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

My C# application has only one form in it and the code has been attached below:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Speech.Recognition;
    using System.Speech.Synthesis;
    using System.IO;
    
    namespace RailVoice
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
    
            SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            SpeechRecognitionEngine speechListener = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            Random random = new Random();
            int voiceTimeOut = 0;
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    
    
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }   
                
            
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands.txt")))));
                speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Default_SpeechRecognized);
                speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
                speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    
                speechListener.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands.txt")))));
                speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(startlistening_SpeechRecognized);
    
            }
    
            private void Default_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
            {
                int randNum;
                string speech = e.Result.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(speech);
    
                if (speech == "Hello")
                {
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hey User");
                }
    
                if(speech == "Bye")
                {
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Byeee user");
                }
    
                if(speech == "What is the date")
                {
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("h mm tt"));
                }
    
                if(speech == "Stop talking")
                {
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                    randNum = random.Next(1, 3);
                    if(randNum == 1)
                    {
                        speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Okay");
                    }
    
                    else if(randNum == 2)
                    {
                        speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Okay sir");
                    }
    
                    else if(randNum == 3)
                    {
                        speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("I will stay quiet");
                    }
    
                }
    
                if(speech == "Stop listening")
                {
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Call me any time you want");
                    speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                    speechListener.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                }
    
                if(speech == "Show commands")
                {
                    string[] MyCommands = File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands");
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                    listBox1.Visible = true;
                    foreach(string commands in MyCommands)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(commands);
                    }
                    
                }
    
                if(speech == "Hide commands")
                {
                    listBox1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
    
            private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
            {
                voiceTimeOut = 0;
            }
    
            private void startlistening_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
            {
                string speech = e.Result.Text;
                   
                if(speech == "Hello assistant")
                {
                    speechListener.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                    speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hello, what do you want");
                    speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                }
            }
    
    
            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(voiceTimeOut == 10)
                {
                    speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                }
    
                else if(voiceTimeOut == 1)
                {
                    speechTimer.Stop();
                    speechListener.RecognizeAsync();
                    voiceTimeOut = 0;
                }
            }
    
           
        }
    }
```

I tried googling but I couldn't find any suitable results.
If anyone knows what this error is, please do drop a message.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The data format isn't being recognized.  You input is e.Result.Text which apparently isn't valid.  There could be a few reasons 1) Youi can't open the file where text is located. 2) The CODEC on you machine may not be correct 3) You have a missing driver 4) Not finding the audio device or you may have multiple audio device and finding wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the unauthorized error, make sure you are running Visual Studio as Administrator

I tried the same code with Administrative option set and it works perfectly fine.

[Code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6SeA.png)

Comment: I tried running administrator and it completely got rid of the error. That was rather an easy fix, thank you so much, you made my day!

Comment: But getting this error fixed, I got another error, System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'No recognizer is installed. I understand that my system doesn't have the recognition package installed, I tried installing all the packages from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh362873(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. I still get the error. Is there anything that I've missed out?

Comment: I got it fixed, apparently I had trouble importing Speech package, instead i used Microsoft.Speech and it works now. Thank you so much for your time! :)

Comment: That's nice to hear